# Ação com scroll em javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-eventos

Meu projeto é fazer uma animação em uma logo usando um efeito css da biblioteca animate.css, a animação ocorrerá em um certo ponto do scroll do site.
Consegui fazer algo, porém ocorre dois bugs ou erros, que são:

1° - Quando o efeito "sumir/FadeOut" execulta, ele reaparece no fim na animação.

2° - O efeito De "voltar/FadeIn" é executado sempre que o ponto é menor, necessito que ele seja executado somente se o efeito FadeOut ja estiver sido feito, e assim vice versa.

Meu código:

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(event){ 
   
  var animacao1 = "animated fadeOutUp";
  var animacao2 = "animated fadeInDown";
  var fimanimacao = "webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend";
   
  if (window.scrollY > 50) {
   $("#cabecalho .logo").addClass(animacao1);
  }
  if (window.scrollY < 50) {
   $("#cabecalho .logo").removeClass(animacao1);
   $("#cabecalho .logo").addClass(animacao2).one(fimanimacao, function(){
    $(this).removeClass(animacao2);
   });
  }
  });
```

```css
#cabecalho {
   height: 270px;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .0);
   position: absolute;
   left: 50%;
   top: 180px;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
  #cabecalho .logo {
   height: 37px;
   width: auto;
   position: absolute;
   left: 40%;
   top: 10%
  }
    #altura{
    height: 1400px;
   }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="cabecalho">
  <img class="logo" alt="Nome" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/41/SEGA_logo.png">
</div>

<div id="altura"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode verificar se a opacidade do elemento é `0` ou `1` para disparar uma animação, evitando que uma atropele a outra.

Coloquei também uma verificação no fim das animações para verificar o scroll, porque o usuário pode alterar antes de terminar a animação, e sendo assim, dispara um evento `scroll` para ajustar o elemento de acordo com o scroll atual.

**Ficaria assim:**

```js
$(window).on('scroll', function(){ 

   var opac = $("#cabecalho .logo").css("opacity"); // pego a opacidade para saber se o elemento está visível

   if(opac == 1 || opac == 0){

      var animacao1 = "animated fadeOutUp";
      var animacao2 = "animated fadeInDown";
      var fimanimacao = "webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend";
      
      if (window.scrollY >= 50 && opac == 1) {
         $("#cabecalho .logo")
         .removeClass(animacao2)
         .addClass(animacao1)
         .one(fimanimacao, function(){
            if(window.scrollY < 50) $(this).trigger("scroll");
         });
      }

      if(window.scrollY < 50 && opac == 0){
         $("#cabecalho .logo")
         .removeClass(animacao1)
         .addClass(animacao2)
         .one(fimanimacao, function(){
            if(window.scrollY > 50) $(this).trigger("scroll");
         });
      }
   }
});
```

```css
#cabecalho {
height: 270px;
width: 100%;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .0);
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top: 180px;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
#cabecalho .logo {
height: 37px;
width: auto;
position: absolute;
left: 40%;
top: 10%
}
#altura{
height: 1400px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cabecalho">
   <img class="logo" alt="Nome" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/41/SEGA_logo.png">
</div>

<div id="altura"></div>
```

Comment: Perfeito cara, obrigado!